# nhibernate 3.3.1.4000 hql join throws a antlr exception

Tags: nhibernate, hql

I'm trying to execute this HQL query:

```
"from Order as order join order.Services as services"
```

but anytime I'm using a join I get this exception:

```
[QuerySyntaxException: Exception of type 'Antlr.Runtime.NoViableAltException' was thrown. near line 1, column 20]
   NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.ErrorCounter.ThrowQueryException() +118
   NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.HqlParseEngine.Parse() +490
   NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory.CreateQueryTranslators(String queryString, String collectionRole, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 filters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory) +89
   NHibernate.Engine.Query.HQLStringQueryPlan.CreateTranslators(String hql, String collectionRole, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 enabledFilters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory) +88
   NHibernate.Engine.Query.HQLStringQueryPlan..ctor(String hql, String collectionRole, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 enabledFilters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory) +71
   NHibernate.Engine.Query.HQLStringQueryPlan..ctor(String hql, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 enabledFilters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory) +50
   NHibernate.Engine.Query.QueryPlanCache.GetHQLQueryPlan(String queryString, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 enabledFilters) +241
   NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.GetHQLQueryPlan(String query, Boolean shallow) +179
   NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.CreateQuery(String queryString) +160
   BL.Queue.GetOrders() in c:\Yayasoft\YTour\YTour\BL\Queues\Queue.cs:66
   YTourWeb.Test.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Yayasoft\YTour\YTour\YTourWeb\Test.aspx.cs:16
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +51
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +92
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +54
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +772
```

This happens when I add a join (any join) if I do a select with no join it works.
Both entities are mapped so it's not the problem of trying to join unmapped properties
any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

In this case, I would say, that the word `order` is incorrectly evaluated as a part of the `ORDER BY`. Try to use different alias, e.g. **orderX** :

```
var hql = "from Order as orderX join orderX.Services as services"
```

Comment: Great, Enjoy NHibernate ;)